# How to round values on a list automatically in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, minecraft

I have a list of values that contain Material, Display name, buy, and sell. The buy and sell values are numbers and I want to write a script that automatically rounds them to the nearest whole number. How could I go about this.

```
Blocks:

  1:
    material: "BOOKSHELF"
    displayname: "Bookshelf"
    buy: 119.12
    sell: 29.78
  2:
    material: "HAY_BLOCK"
    displayname: "Hay Bale"
    buy: 47.25
    sell: 11.82
```

EDIT: Hi sorry for not giving more explanation the list is here: https://hastebin.com/kobojekeda.yaml . It is also a yaml file. What I am trying to achieve is to round the buy and sell values to the nearest whole number. Then I need it to create a file/update an old one with the new values replacing the old ones.

Comment: Please include the actual list of values.  Are these dicts?

Comment: Could you include the list in your question?

Comment: Please show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. See also: [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
BOOKSHELF = {
    'material': 'BOOKSHELF',
    'display': 'Bookshelf',
    'buy': 119.12,
    'sell': 29.78
}

HAY_BLOCK = {
    'material': 'HAY_BLOCK',
    'display': 'Hay Bale',
    'buy': 47.65,
    'sell': 11.28
}

def main():
     block_list = [BOOKSHELF, HAY_BLOCK]
     for block in block_list:
          block['buy'] = round(block['buy'])
          block['sell'] = round(block['sell'])
     print(block_list)
     return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the round() function in Python. The round function will round up to the nearest whole number.

Not exactly sure how to set this up without knowing more about your project, but here’s an idea. Or you can make a function and pass the values through that.

```
1:
material: "BOOKSHELF"
displayname: "Bookshelf"
buy: round(119.12)
sell: round(29.78)
2:
material: "HAY_BLOCK"
displayname: "Hay Bale"
buy: round(47.25)
sell: round(11.82)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the book info in a list and you need to round the floating values into the nearest integer, perhaps you can try this;

```
info_list = ["BOOKSHELF", "Bookshelf", 119.12, 29.78]
rounded = [int(round(element)) if isinstance(element, float) else element for element in info_list]
```

if not, just use int(round('price goes here')).

This is the output

```
['BOOKSHELF', 'Bookshelf', 119, 30]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
your_list = ["BOOKSHELF", "Bookshelf", 119.12, 29.78]
new_list = []
for item in your_list:
    if isinstance(item, float):
        new_list.append(round(item))
    else:
        new_list.append(item)

print(new_list)
```

Explanation...

- Create a new empty list,
- loop through your old list
- For every item in your old list that is a float,
- apply round function to it
- now append this rounded value to new list
- for all other values in list, just append them as is to new list

Comment: Hello, would I do a yaml.load = your_list, because YAML isnt a list in of itself.

Comment: My answer was based on your question before you edit it. I was not aware of the edited version untill after I uploaded my answer.